# Print single JSON Object as a CSV in C#

Tags: c#, json, csv, json.net

I'm trying to print a single JObject as a CSV row

for example:

```
{"result": {
"id": "24095",
"hostid": "24094",
"name": "host1.fqdn.com",
"ipaddress" : "192.168.1.184"
}
}
```

as

```
id,hostid,name,ipaddress
24095,24094,host1.fqdn.com,192.168.1.184
```

I can easily iterate through the object with

```
foreach (var item in jobj) {
   Console.Write(item.Key + ",");
}
```

but I end up with a , at the end of the header

I tried

```
for (int i = 0; i < jobj.Count; i++)...
```

but I'm having trouble accessing i.Key. I'm doing something wrong here but i'm not sure what.

Any ideas on how i can print all the keys in an object as a CSV minus a , at the end?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code.

```
string result = string.Empty;

foreach (var item in jobj)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
    {
        result += ",";
    }
    result += item.Key;
}
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over all except the last one, then use the last one outside the block.

```
for (int i = 0; i < jobj.Count-1; i++) {
    Console.Write(jobj[i].Key + ", ");
}

Console.WriteLine(jobj[jobj.Count-1].Key);
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. I have no trouble iterating over all the items but I'm trying to get just the keys. Not the values. So jobj[i].key is what i'm after but it's not available as a property.

Comment: I dont recognise JObject, what is it apart of?